# Loop space and stable homotopy theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

The Bott periodicity theorem for unitary group $U(n)$ says that
$$ \pi_{i-1}(U) \simeq \pi_{i+1}(U) $$
How can I prove, using this theorem, that
$$ \Omega (U) \simeq BU \times \mathbb{Z} ?$$
What is precisely the loop space $\Omega(U)$?

Comment: $\Omega U\cong BU\times\mathbb Z$ implies $\pi_{i-1}(U)\cong\pi_{i+1}(U)$ but I don't think there is an implication in the opposite direction.

Comment: @ArthurStuart I've provided an answer to your question below; let me know if it answers your question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My memory of this is that the K-theory functor on the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is represented by $BU\times \mathbb{Z}$, that is, $K(X)= [X,BU\times \mathbb{Z}]$ for all compact Hausdorff spaces $X$. If we're dealing with reduced K-theory, then we're looking at basepoint preserving homotopy classes of maps: $\tilde{K}(X)=\langle X,BU\times \mathbb{Z} \rangle$.

The K-theoretic form of Bott periodicity is that $\tilde{K}(X)\cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma^2 X)$, i.e., $\langle X, BU\times \mathbb{Z} \rangle \cong \langle  \Sigma^2 X, BU\times \mathbb{Z} \rangle$. The (reduced) suspension/loopspace adjunction implies that $\langle \Sigma^2 X, BU\times \mathbb{Z}\rangle \cong \langle X,\Omega^{2} (BU\times \mathbb{Z}) \rangle$. Therefore, $\langle X, BU\times \mathbb{Z} \rangle \cong \langle X, \Omega^{2} (BU\times \mathbb{Z}) \rangle$ for all compact Hausdorff spaces $X$. Yoneda's lemma implies that $\Omega^{2} (BU\times \mathbb{Z})\cong BU\times \mathbb{Z}$ in the homotopy category of pointed topological spaces, i.e., that $\Omega^{2} (BU\times \mathbb{Z})$ is homotopy equivalent to $BU\times \mathbb{Z}$.

However, $\Omega (BU\times \mathbb{Z})\cong U$; indeed, it's basic that taking the loop spaces of the classifying space of a topological group always gives you back the topological group. Therefore, $\Omega U\cong BU\times \mathbb{Z}$ (and vice-versa!).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know how can I prove that are equivalent $\pi_{i-1}(U) \simeq \pi_{i+1}(U)$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times BU \to \Omega(U)$ ia a weak homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @ArthurStuart The condition $\pi_{i-1}(U)\cong \pi_{i+1}(U)$ for all positive integers $i$ is equivalent to the statement that $\mathbb{Z}\times BU$ and $\Omega(U)$ have isomorphic homotopy groups. However, two spaces (or even two CW complexes) may have isomorphic homotopy groups without being homotopy equivalent. On the other hand, Whitehead's theorem states that a map $f:X\to Y$ between CW complexes that *induces* isomorphisms on all homotopy groups must be a homotopy equivalence. So, in general, I don't think there's a way of proving the assertion that you wish to prove.

Comment: @ArthurStuart We aren't explicitly given the isomorphisms $\pi_{i-1}(U)\cong \pi_{i+1}(U)$. For example, $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ have isomorphic homotopy groups (their universal covers, $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^{\infty}$, are homotopy equivalent). However, $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ cannot be homotopy equivalent because their homology groups aren't isomorphic: $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ has non-trivial homology in arbitrarily large degrees whereas $\mathbb{RP}^2$ does not!

Comment: What is the difference among $[\cdot, \cdot]$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$? Why $\Omega(BU \times \mathbb{Z}) \cong U$?

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I prove that $\Omega(U) \simeq BU \times \mathbb{Z}$? Where $BU:= colim_n BU(n)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ has the diescrete topology?... I know that $K(X) \simeq \tilde{K}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z} \simeq K(pt)$.

Comment: @ArthurStuart Hi Arthur, I didn't see your messages there until now so apologies for the delay. $\left\langle \cdot, \cdot \right\rangle$ denotes basepoint preserving homotopy classes of maps and $\left[\cdot,\cdot\right]$ denotes homotopy classes of maps in the general sense (not necessarily basepoint preserving). Also, $\Omega(BU\times\mathbb{Z})\cong \Omega(BU)$ (this should be obvious; basepointed loops all live in one component of the space in question). Are you familiar with the basic properties of classifying spaces, e.g., $\Omega(BU)\cong U$? If not, then do you want me to prove this?

Comment: No... I don't know why $\Omega(BU) \simeq U$ and why $\langle \Sigma^2(X), BU \times \mathbb{X} \rangle \simeq \langle X,\Omega^2(BU \times \mathbb{Z}) \rangle$. Is there a method... without using Yoneda's lemma, to prove that $\Omega^2(BU \times \mathbb{Z}) \simeq BU \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ArthurStuart I think the method I suggested above is not difficult if one thinks about it. I've explained above in detail each of the points that you're asking about. I've also explained why the implication you're asking about in your question is unlikely, if not impossible. Could you tell me which parts of my explanation you don't understand? The statement $\Omega(BU)\cong U$ is far more fundamental than Bott periodicity so I don't think one can proceed without understanding this. The second statement is just the loopspace-suspension adjunction ...

Comment: @ArthurStuart ... The loopspace-suspension adjunction is a claim that might be good to prove as an exercise; it's not hard and it's important to understand. (***Exercise***: Prove that [\Sigma X,Y]\cong [X,\Omega Y] for basepointed topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. The notation $\Sigma X$ denotes the reduced suspension; basically, we're taking the suspension and identifying a "line" between the top and bottom points passing through the basepoint of $X$.) Have you tried looking up the Wikipedia article on the Yoneda lemma? It's an important thing to understand that appears quite often.

Comment: @ArthurStuart Bott periodicity, namely $\Omega^2(BU\times \mathbb{Z})\cong BU\times\mathbb{Z}$, has many proofs. I think a proof you might like is by Bruno Harris: "Bott Periodicity via Simplicial Spaces". The link to a PDF is at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869380901945 . The paper is only 4 pages long (not including the references); it's really worth reading it.

Comment: As you said, I'm agree with the fact that the $2$-periodicity in the language of $K$-theory is $\tilde{K}(X) \cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma^2(X))$, but why this implies that $\Omega(BU) \cong U$?

Comment: @ArthurStuart I don't think I claimed that particular implication. In fact, I believe that the claim $\Omega(BU)\cong U$ is elementary and follows from the basic theory of classifying spaces. The hard claim (which is essentially the statement of Bott periodicity) is that $\Omega U\cong BU\times \mathbb{Z}$. However, the K-theoretic interpretation of Bott periodicity, i.e., $\tilde{K}(X)\cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma^2(X))$ implies that $BU\times\mathbb{Z}\cong \Omega^2(BU\times\mathbb{Z})$. Since $\Omega(BU\times\mathbb{Z})\cong U$ (the easy part), it follows that $\Omega(U)\cong BU\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArthurStuart The implication $\left[\tilde{K}(X)\cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma^2(X))\right]\implies \left[BU\times\mathbb{Z}\cong \Omega^2(BU\times\mathbb{Z})\right]$ follows from Yoneda's lemma: the reduced K-theory functor is represented in the homotopy category of pointed compact Hausdorff spaces by $BU\times\mathbb{Z}$. However, the K-theoretic interpretation of Bott periodicity, $\tilde{K}(X)\cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma^2(X))$, implies that this functor is also represented by $\Omega^2(BU\times\mathbb{Z})$. Yoneda's lemma implies that $BU\times\mathbb{Z}\cong \Omega^2(BU\times\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @ArthurStuart May I suggest that you ask the question: "Why does delooping the classifying space of a topological group $G$ return a space homotopy equivalent to $G$" as a separate question on this website? In symbols, you could write as further details that you'd like to know why $\Omega(BG)\cong G$ for a topological group $G$ (the case $\Omega(BU)\cong U$ is a special case of this). I could answer this question for you but I feel it would be better to ask it as a separate question and possibly someone who has more time than me at the moment can give you a quick and detailed answer.

Comment: @AmithesDatta I'm sorry, but my question was another: I asked why the $K$-theoretical interpretation of Bott periodicity is $\tilde{K}(X) \cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma^2(X))$